# How employee can submit leave request

Tags: odoo-14

I am using odoo 14 community edition. I want to implement Leave module. I have go through functionality but could not understand how employee can submit leave request at his own?

Is there any option on web portal or using email etc.

Please guide.

Comment: I think should create organization chat for your employee

Comment: This is good idea

Comment: any other solution?